# CORS - Spring Boot 3 Update

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I updated my Vaadin application to Spring Boot 3 and now I received on startup the following warning

```
Cache miss for REQUEST dispatch to '/ui/login' (previous null). Performing CorsConfiguration lookup. This is logged once only at WARN level, and every time at TRACE.
```

By adding the following Bean the error disappers:

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://test.com"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

The message disappers with this Bean, but I'm not sure whether it is correct. I read a lot about CORS but do not understand it in detail. Maybe anyone can help me or tell me how to handle it correct.

This is my WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class TestWebSecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> {
            requests.requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(MAPPING + "**")).hasAuthority("abc");
            requests.anyRequest().permitAll();
        });

        http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.csrf((customizer) -> customizer.disable());
        http.headers((customizer) -> customizer.disable());
        
        return http.build();
    }
    
        @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("xyz")
            .password("xyz")
            .authorities("abc");
    }
    
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does your security configuration look like? If you use VaadinWebSecurity you don't have to configure CORS yourself

Comment: I do not have a special security for Vaadin, but I get this error. But I have some additional REST interfaces and I created a specific WebSecurityConfig (not for Vaadin). I added it to the first post, because unfortunately I was not able to add the source code within a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know behavior since Spring Boot 3.2.0 because of the Spring Framework change described [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31588). The fix is already [implement](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/14128) in Spring Security and to be included in Spring Boot 3.2.1 later this December.

Comment: So this means that I do not have to add such a configuration (CorsConfigurationSource) and it is moreless only a warning message without any impact to my application?

Comment: Short answer yes and it's going to be gone in boot 3.2.1

Comment: No I get a similar message by downloading a PDF file by cklicking on a Anchor (with spring boot 3.2.1) "2024-02-16 14:53:23,762  WARN | https-jsse-nio-18443-exec-29 | o.s.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector | Cache miss for REQUEST dispatch to '/ui/VAADIN/dynamic/resource/2/ed8f6654-13ef-4a2e-b525-5178bda12d02/test.pdf'  (previous CachedResult for REQUEST dispatch to '/ui/VAADIN/dynamic/resource/2/test.pdf').  Performing CorsConfiguration lookup. This is logged once only at WARN level, and every time at TRACE."